# Do any Java standard libraries have a container class with 3 data types or more?

Tags: java, spring

I have a method and I would like to return 3 types of data from it. I need a container class for that. I don't want to build it, but use a standard library class for it if this option exists.

I want to return from the method the following data at the same time:

1. `LocalDate`
2. `LocalTime`
3. Message Object

My question - Is there a Class/Data Structure with Generics in the Java Standard libraries which I can use as container that I can assign the respective values to and that will allow me to return all these 3 values at the same time without me having to create it or use external libraries for?

If not, what other options to solve this issue do I have ?

Comment: normallest would be to create your own response type, but what stops you from returning an Object[] with three elements in it?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, or why creating a simple data structure is hard, but you can just use `Object[]` if the actual type isn't important.

Comment: `Map<LocalDateTime, Message>` comes quite near.

Comment: That i what records are for, alsoe why not use `LocalDateTime` instead of seperated fields? Lets you return 2 fields instead of 3.

Comment: Create your own class. That documents what the meaning of the association between the three fields is.

Comment: For my specific case I cannot use LocalDateTime nor can I create a custom class. I believe an Object[] would be more apropiate for what I need to do. Thanks !

Comment: If you use Apache Commons Lang, [it has a `Triple` object](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Triple.html).

Comment: "nor can I create a custom class" - Could you elaborate on the why? Seems to be an odd situation in which you can write code but cannot add classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I once read a comment by one of the original designers who stated that they thought about providing classes like Pair, Triple or Tuple. However, they decided against it. Why? Because those classes are very generic and while it often makes sense to give proper names to the "things" in those classes. Example was `Point(int x, int y)` instead of `Pair(int a, int b)`. - So today "I don't want to build a container class" isn't a valid argument on most cases.

Java 17+'s records make it easy to build those containers:

```
public static record Message(LocalDate date, LocalTime time, Object msg) {};
```

That's it.

Even without that creating those containers often is very simple by either having the IDE generate the methods or using some library like Lombok.

Comment: Note that records are always immutable.

Comment: @dan1st yes, should be mentioned. But for the OP's purpose that should be sufficient :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to return multiple values with different data types is by using arrays.
In your method, append your desired values into an array and then return the array itself.

You can use a common parent type as the array's type if you want to return an array of different reference types.

```java
LocalData[] getLocalDataArray() {
  
    LocalData[] localDataArray = new LocalData[3];

    localDataArray[0] = java.time.LocalDate.now();   // Date
    localDataArray[1] = java.time.Time.now(); // Time
    localDataArray[2] = "A message"; // String

    return localDataArray;
}
```

You can find more info on [How to Return Multiple Values From a Java Method](https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-return-multiple-values)

Comment: About the purpose of a class itself to hand code one. With time it may as be converted to a "long timestamp" and converted by a method in the custom object on retrieval. If not then a DTO is about the only other clearly fielded object. Nuts!

Comment: You realize that `LocalData` won't fit any of the types you want to assign to the array? If it it was `LocalDate` then only the first assignment would work at all. You _could_ use `Object[]` instead but that's horrible when you need the elements back.